# How to get a orthonormal coordinate frame from a 3 dimension point and a unit vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a 3 dimension point p, and a unit length vector z, how can we calculate a orthonormal coordinate frame?

Comment: The result should be a homogeneous 4*4 matrix, which maps the points & vectors in coordinates of this frame, to points & vectors in the coordinates of the world frame.

Comment: Do you know [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)?